# Adding a Listbox to a main object

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a main object in a form and wish to add a select list, just like for a ComBoBox
I think this is a C or Windows question and in reality I'm writting in Delphi.

can I Create a subclass is that possible and how
I've been playing around with these staments

```
ChildHandle := GetWindow(ChildHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT);
and use SetWindowLong(ChildHandle, GWL_STYLE, Longint(FListInstance));
```

How should I go about this and what pit falls are thier
Can i read about this somewhere?

Comment: You seem to be regressing in your ability to ask coherent questions, Lex. Do you mean to say you have a custom *component* (all things are objects, so *object* isn't a useful description), and you want to display a drop-down list box from that component? What did you expect GetWindow and SetWindowLong to do toward that goal? Have you gotten to the point of creating the list that you want to drop down?

Comment: Why didn't you log in using [your previous account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/665392/lexdean)?

Comment: I'd like to help here but I can't figure out what the question is - please explain clearly using Delphi terminology. Are you trying to create a combo box using win32 calls instead of Delphi components? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Rob: probably because he has a history of doing so. At least I distinctly remember a les dean (with/out space) that had separate accounts for every question, though that can no longer be "traced" as all his previous accounts had/have been merged. He had seemed to have gotten the hang of using a single account, but apparently it hasn't stuck...

Comment: Forget everything you think you knoy, buy a copy of Petzold, read it and learn win32 properly.

Comment: I'm talking about SubClassing, but SubClassing as I understand can only be done at creation time. I need to make changes after Creation time.

Comment: @lex - Search for the word "subclass" in `SetWindowLong`'s [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll see that the index you'd use is GWL_WNDPROC.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a closer look on
[SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though **SetWindowLong** is also a good methog (see Sertac Akyuz' answer). If you're writing code for 32- and 64-bit systems then use [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).